# Interpolate variables into string in python and coffeescript

Tags: python, string, dictionary, coffeescript, namespaces

in python :

```
namespace = { 'host': 'facebook.com', 'user': '{somehost}/user/83426347' }
namespace['user'].format(somehost=namespace['host'])
```

> facebook.com/user/83426347

in coffee script I have the same:

```
namespace=
    host: 'facebook.com'
    user: 'facebook.com/user/42342342'
```

I am new to CS so how to handle same behaviour to pythons?

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
language = "Python"
greet = "I love %s" % language
```

Coffeescript

```
language = "Coffescript"
greet = "I love #{language}"
```

Answer (score 1):

as seen in [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880578/coffeescript-version-of-string-format-sprintf-etc-for-javascript-or-node-js)

```
String.prototype.format = ->
  args = arguments
  return this.replace /{(\d+)}/g, (match, number) ->
    return if typeof args[number] isnt 'undefined' then args[number] else match
```

Then you can do something like:

```
namespace=
    host: 'facebook.com'
    user: '{0}/user/42342342'
namespace.user = namespace.user.format namespace.host
```